# How can I add a scroll bar to a DIV?

Tags: css

I have a DIV on my page. Within the DIV I have other DIVs which I customize to look like buttons. Here's an example:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQ7Ev/)

Because I have so many buttons I need to have some means of scrolling so that the user can scroll down to the correct button (DIV). In the fiddle this is done using an iframe but I think I read that this can give problems with search engine optimization.

Is there some way that I can add a scroll bar to my DIV? I have never seen this done but I hope someone has some ideas.

Thanks,

Comment: Although you could use `height:Xpx;overflow:auto;` on the outter div, maybe you should refactor your design. It is better to work with the browser scrollbar (especially for mobile display!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to use some JQuery, [JScroll Pane plugin is exactly what you're looking for](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

Comment: This looks very nice. I wonder if there is anything more like JScroll Pane? Have you seen others? I will go and have a look now.

Comment: There are other plugins, but this one is the best and most popular. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

Add

`padding-right:30px; overflow:auto; height:500px;`

to the main `div`

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/AQ7Ev/7/

You will need to set a `height` to make it work.

Also, you will need `padding` so the scroll bar does not overlap the content.

Comment: This looks good but what if the user changes the height of the main page? Would it be possible to set the top: and bottom: of that DIV instead of setting the height?

Comment: Not much you can do about resizing, I think, other than set the height to something manageable...not the 500px I used for the example.  However, to ensure that full buttons (and not partial buttons) are showing, you should make the `height` a multiple of 25px + 4px (your `height` and `padding` for each button)

Answer (score 0):

set the height for the containing div + overflow:auto or : scroll

```
<div style="width: 200px; height:240px;overflow:auto">
      <div class = "abc" >.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a height on the div and add `overflow:auto;`. I forked your fiddle, here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/vxTqT/.